# Delete all consecutive duplicates

Tags: substitute, macro, global-command

I have a file that looks like this.

```
Move to 230.00
Hold
Hold
Hold
Hold
Hold
Hold
Move to 00.00
Hold 
Hold 
Hold 
Hold 
Hold 
FooBar
Hold 
Spam
Hold
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Move to 230.00
Hold
Move to 00.00
Hold 
FooBar
Hold
Spam
Hold
```

I'm sure there must be a way that vim could quickly do this, but I can't quite wrap my head around how. Is this beyond the power of macros, and needs vimscript?

Also, it's OK if I have to apply the same macro to each block of "Holds". It doesn't have to be a single one macro that gets the whole file, although that would be awesome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the following command should work :

```
 :%s/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$/\1/
```

Explanation :

We use the substitution command on the whole file to change `pattern` into `string` :

```
:%s/pattern/string/
```

Here `pattern` is `^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$` and `string` is `\1`.

`pattern` can be broken down like this :

```
^\(subpattern1\)\(subpattern2\)\+$
```

`^` and `$` match respectively a beginning of line and an end of line.

`\(` and `\)` are used to enclose `subpattern1` so that we can refer to it later by the special number `\1`.
They are also used to enclose `subpattern2` so that we can repeat it 1 or more times with the quantifier `\+`.

`subpattern1` is `.*`
`.` is a metacharacter matching any character except new line and `*` is a quantifier that matches the last character 0, 1 or more times.
So `.*` matches any text containing no new line.

`subpattern2` is `\n\1`
`\n` matches a new line and `\1` matches the same text that was matched inside the first `\(`, `\)` which here is `subpattern1`.

So `pattern` can be read like this :
*a beginning of line (`^`) followed by any text containing no new line (`.*`) followed by a new line (`\n`) then the same text (`\1`), the latter two being repeated one or more times (`\+`), and finally an end of line (`$`)*.

Wherever `pattern` is matched (a block of identical lines), the substitution command replaces it with `string` which here is `\1` (the first line of the block).

If you want to see which blocks of lines will be affected without changing anything in your file, you can enable the `hlsearch` option and add the `n` substitution flag at the end of the command :

```
:%s/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$/\1/n
```

For more granular control, you can also ask for a confirmation before changing each block of lines by adding the `c` substitution flag instead :

```
:%s/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$/\1/c
```

For more information on the substitution command read `:help :s`,
for the substitution flags `:help s_flags`,
for the various metacharacters and quantifiers read `:help pattern-atoms`,
and for regular expressions in vim read [this](http://vimregex.com/).

Edit: [Wildcard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/delete-all-consecutive-duplicates#comment8232_5366) fixed a problem in the command by adding a `$` at the end of `pattern`.

Also [BloodGain](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5370/4939) has a shorter and more readable version of the same command.

Comment: Nice; your command needs a `$` in it, though.  Otherwise it will do unexpected things with a line that *starts* with identical text to the previous line, but has some other trailing characters.  Also note that the basic command you gave is functionally equivalent to my answer of `:%!uniq`, but the highlight and confirmation flags are nice.

Comment: You're right, I've just checked and if one of the duplicate lines contain a different trailing character, the command doesn't behave like expected. I don't know how to fix it, the atom `\n` matches an end of line and should prevent this but it doesn't. I tried adding a `$` just after `.*` with no success. I'm going to try and fix it, but if I can't, maybe I will delete my answer or add a warning at the end. Thank you for pointing this problem.

Comment: Try `:%s/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$/\1/`

Comment: You should consider that `$` matches end of *string*, not end of line.  This is technically not true—but when you put characters after it other than a few exceptions, it matches a literal `$` instead of anything special.  So using `\n` is better for multi-line matches.  (See `:help /$`)

Comment: I think you are right in that `\n` can be used anywhere inside the regex whereas `$` should probably be used only at the end. Just to make a difference between the two, I've edited the answer by writing that `\n` matches a newline (which instinctively makes you think that there is still some text after) whereas `$` matches an end of line (which makes you think that there is nothing left).

Answer (score 12):

Try the following:

```
:%s;\v^(.*)(\n\1)+$;\1;
```

As with [saginaw's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5366/5190), this uses Vim's :substitute command. However, it takes advantage of a couple of extra features to improve readability:

1. Vim lets us use any non-alphanumeric ASCII character except backslash (**\**), double-quote (**"**), or pipe (**|**) to divide our match/replace/flags text. Here, I selected semicolon (**;**), but you can choose another.
2. Vim provides "magic" settings for regular expressions, so that characters are interpreted for their special meanings instead of requiring a backslash escape. This is helpful to reduce verbosity, and because it is more consistent than the "nomagic" default. Starting with **`\v`** means "very magic," or all characters except alphanumeric (**A-z0-9**) and underscore (**_**) have special meaning.

The meaning of the components are:

> **%** *for the whole file*
>
> **s** *substitute*
>
> **;** *begin substitute string*
>
> **\v** *"very magic"*
>
> **^** *beginning of line*
>
> **(.*)** *0 or more of **any** character (group 1)*
>
> **(\n\1)+** *newline followed by (group 1 match text), 1 or more times (group 2)*
>
> **$** *end of line* (or in this case, think *next character must be a newline*)
>
> **;** *begin replace string*
>
> **\1** *group 1 match text*
>
> **;** *end of command* or *begin flags*

Comment: I really like your answer, because it's more readable but also because it made me better understand the difference between `\n` and `$`. `\n` adds something to the pattern : the character new line that tells vim that the following text is on a new line. Whereas `$` doesn't add anything to the  pattern, it simply forbids a match to be made if the next character outside of the pattern isn't a new line. At least, it's what I've understood by reading your answer and `:help zero-width`.

Comment: And the same must be true for `^`, it doesn't add anything to the pattern, it just prevents a match to be made if the previous character outside of the pattern is not a new line...

Comment: @saginaw You have it exactly right, and that's a good explanation. In regular expressions, some characters can be though of as _control characters_. For example, `+` means "repeat the preceding expression (character or group) 1 or more times," but does not match anything itself. The `^` means "cannot start in the middle of the string" and `$` means "cannot end in the middle of the string." Notice I didn't say "line,"  but "string" there. Vim treats each line as a string by default -- and that's where `\n` comes in. It tells Vim to consume a newline to try to make this match.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove ALL adjacent identical lines, not just `Hold`, you can do it extremely easily with an external filter from within `vim`:

`:%!uniq` (in a Unix environment).

If you want to do it directly in `vim`, it's actually very tricky.  I think there is a way, but for the general case it is very tricky to make it 100% functional and I haven't worked out all the bugs yet.

However, for *this specific* case, since you can visually see that the next line that is non-duplicate doesn't start with the same character, you can use:

```
:+,./^[^H]/-d
```

The `+` means the line after the current line.  The . refers to the current line.  The `/^[^H]/-` means the line before (`-`) the next line that doesn't start with H.

Then d is delete.

Comment: While the substitute and global Vim commands are good exercises, calling `uniq` (either from within vim or using the shell) is how I would solve this. For one thing, I'm pretty sure `uniq` will handle lines that are blank/all spaces as equivalent (didn't test it), but that would be much harder to capture with a regex. It also means not "reinventing the wheel" while I'm trying to get work done.

Comment: The ability to feed text through external tools is why I usually recommend Vim *and* Cygwin on Windows. Vim and shell simply *belong* together.

Answer (score 2):

A Vim-based answer:

```
:%s/\(^.*\n\)\1\{1,}/\1
```

= Replace *every line followed by itself at least once*, with that same line.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on an [old (2003) vim(golf)](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vim/conversations/topics/36621) by Preben Gulberg and Piet Delport.

- It's roots lies in `%g/^\v(.*)\n\1$/d`
- Unlike the other solutions, it has been [encapsulated](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-system-tools/blob/master/plugin/system_utils.vim#L195) into a function so, it doesn't modify the search register, nor the unnamed register.
- And it also has been encapsulated into a command in order to simplify its usage:

  - `:Uniq` (equivalent to `:%Uniq`),
  - `:1,Uniq` (from the start of the buffer to the current line),
  - visually select lines + hit `:Uniq<cr>` (expanded by vim into `:'<,'>Uniq`)
  - etc (`:h range`)

Here is the code:

```
command! -range=% -nargs=0 Uniq <line1>,<line2>call s:EmuleUniq()

function! s:EmuleUniq() range
  let l1 = a:firstline
  let l2 = a:lastline
  if l1 < l2
    " Note the "-" to avoid spilling over the end of the range
    " Note also the use of ":delete", along with the black hole register "_"
    silent exe l1.','l2.'-g/^\(.*\)\n\1$/d _'

    call histdel('search', -1)          " necessary
    " let @/ = histget('search', -1)    " useless within a function
  endif
endfunction
```

Note: their firsts attempts were:

```
" Version1 from: Preben 'Peppe' Guldberg <peppe {at} xs4all {dot} nl>
" silent exe l1 . ',' . (l2 - 1) . 's/^\(.*\)\%(\n\%<' . (l2 + 1)
      " \ . 'l\1$\)\+/\1/e'

" Version from: Piet Delport <pjd {at} 303.za {dot} net>
" silent exe l1.','l2.'g/^\%<'.l2.'l\(.*\)\n\1$/d'
```

Answer (score 2):

One more, assuming Vim 7.4.218 or later:

```
function! s:Uniq(line1, line2)
    let cursor = getcurpos()
    let lines = uniq(getline(a:line1, a:line2))
    if setline(a:line1, lines) == 0 && len(lines) <= a:line2 - a:line1
        silent execute (a:line1 + len(lines)) . ',' . a:line2 . 'd _'
    endif
    call setpos('.', cursor)
endfunction

command! -range=% Uniq call <SID>Uniq(<line1>, <line2>)
```

This isn't necessarily better than the other solutions, though.